# Can't set cells in UITableView from NSMutableArray getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Can anyone help I am trying to set the values of the cells in a table view but I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
          static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView depueueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
          if (cell == nil) {
               cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
               cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
          }

          cell.textLabel.text = [webRef objectAtIndec:indexPath.row];

          return cell;
}
```

I am trying to set the values from an NSMutableArray. There are objects in the array I can print them to the console but not into the cells.

Comment: Also if I replace the [webRef objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] with @"Hello World" sets the cell values to Hello World. and in the numberOfRowsInSection  sets the correct about of rows to the number of objects in the array.

Comment: You have strings in there, right? How is the array initialized?

Comment: It seems like webRef doesn't contain all strings. Can you check? can you type something like this?
id obj = [webRef objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
  cell.textLabel.text=(NSString *)obj;
} else {
  cell.textLabel.text=@"This is not a string...";
}
and see the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. I was not retaining anything when declaring the Arrays. Thanks everyone for the help you have provided.